# How do I create a schema for all tables of a database in Informix with DBeaver?

Tags: informix, dbeaver

I would like to generate the schema for all tables with foreign keys and indexes in the database for a database in Informix. I use DBeaver as the database tool.

Is it possible to use DBeaver (version 23.2) to generate the schema for a database with the above criteria?

Answer (score 1):

It seems that in the Community Edition 23.2.4 of DBeaver there is no possibility to display the foreign keys for Data Definition Language.

According to the Java developer LonwoLonwo it seems to be possible in other editions of DBeaver to display the foreign keys via the button "Separate FK" below the Data Definition Language for one or more tables.

See my question on GitHub:
https://github.com/orgs/dbeaver/discussions/21850

Comment: And is it correct to infer that the limitation applies to all DBMS, not just Informix?

Comment: Hi @JonathanLeffler, I assume that this conclusion that the function to activate the foreign keys in DBeaver can be concluded for all database instances. Unfortunately, the developer LonwoLonwo did not answer my further question in the linked GitHub discussion to substantiate my statement 100 percent.